# Searching with AND across multiple indexes Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have multiple indexes and can search each independently but I'd like a consolidated search across all indexes. I've seen several posts recommending using a multireader but I can't get the results I want. See my unit test below for more details.

```c#
        [Test]
    public void Given_Muliple_Documents_With_SameId_Diff_Attribute_Expect_Matches()
    {
        //Arrange
        var source1 = new[] {new Stub("1", "Car"), new Stub("2", "Bike"), new Stub("3", "Car")};
        var source2 = new[] { new Stub("1", "Ford"), new Stub("3", "Ducati"), new Stub("4", "Honda") };
        var idField = "Id";
        var searchField = "FullText";

        var directory1 = CreateRAMDirectory(source1, idField, searchField);
        var directory2 = CreateRAMDirectory(source2, idField, searchField);

        //Act
        var reader = IndexReader.Open(directory1, true);
        var reader2 = IndexReader.Open(directory2, true);

        var results = new List<string>();
        using (IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(new MultiReader(reader, reader2)))
        {
            using (Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
            {
                var queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new[] { "FullText" }, analyzer)
                {
                    AllowLeadingWildcard = true
                };

                var query = queryParser.Parse("CAR AND Ford");

                var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(1000, true);

                searcher.Search(query, collector);

                var matches = collector.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;

                foreach (var item in matches)
                {
                    var id = item.Doc;
                    var doc = searcher.Doc(id);
                    var row = doc.Get("Id");
                    results.Add(row);
                }
            }
        }

        //Assert
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new[] {"1"}, results.Distinct().ToArray());
    }
```

The following stub and helper method definitions

```c#
        public class Stub
    {
        public Stub(string id, string attrib)
        {
            Id = id;
            Attrib = attrib;
        }

        public string Id { get; }
        public string Attrib { get; }
    }

    private static RAMDirectory CreateRAMDirectory(Stub[] source1, string idField, string searchField)
    {
        var directory = new RAMDirectory();

        using (Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30))
        using (var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(1000)))
        {
            foreach (var row in source1)
            {
                var document = new Document();
                document.Add(new Field(idField, row.Id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
                document.Add(new Field(searchField, $"{row.Attrib}", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
                writer.AddDocument(document);
            }

            writer.Optimize();
            writer.Flush(true, true, true);
        }
        return directory;
    }
```

Comment: At a glance, it doesn't look like any of the documents you are indexing contain both "Car" and "Ford".  The query `Car AND Ford` would require any matching documents to contain both.

Comment: Yeh I'm wanting to search across the documents as if they are one document (same Id field). I understood the MultiReader was the way to go for this. If it isn't, is there another way to achieve this given the documents are partitioned in this way?

Comment: No, Multireader won't do that. It's just to allow you to search multiple indexes. What you are talking about is basically a relational join. This blog post goes over the use of BlockJoinQuery: [Searching relational content with Lucene's BlockJoinQuery](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html)